# Is it possible access other transaction?

Tags: java, spring, web, transactions

I developing web application using spring, mybatis. I want to commit or rollback to other transaction in some transaction.

Is it possible sharing transaction object throw seperated transactions?

Comment: Why are you looking for such an odd design? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Just to know that is possible. And I don't think that is terrible design. If it can, I will get many chance to attempt

Comment: *If it can, I will get many chance to attempt* this is exactly what I'm asking. What do you need to achieve in order that you need such odd design? Based on what you explain, we can reply with more info or just explain why it cannot be done.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok. I trying control database trasactions on my web application that show list of many transactions of not commit states, and user can commit of rollback in time their want. My access is wrong?

Comment: Sadly, you cannot do that in a decent database engine.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Even if maintain org.springframework.transaction.XXXTransaction instance as application scope value?

Comment: In short: no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may not be much informative but it's to the best of my knowledge.

A transaction is an indivisible unit of work. It shouldn't remain open for a long time as it eats up resources plus it keeps your object in an inconsistent state. One should best let the framework transaction manager manage the transactions until & unless writing your own management logic is imperative.
Besides, keeping all this mind, spring provides two ways of implementing transactions declarative & programmatic.

Programmatic provides you a greater control over transactions. There are many transaction design patterns, [this](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/JTDS) & [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts2/) are excellent resources if you want to read in depth about designing transactions in Java Spring.

Comment: Thank you for answer my stupid question faithfully

Comment: you can accept the answer if it resolves your query